# numbers change when saving with pandas to a .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict={"10024128313803797": "42288,41851,2758249,115436583248,1194687"}
```

i am trying to store values in a `csv` file using following code:

```
for i in my_dict:
    tashih=my_dict[i].split(',')
    my_dict[i]=tashih
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.to_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf8',index=False)
```

but when i use pandas, it changes key from "10024128313803797" to "100241283138037**00**"
[here is a picture of opened test.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoCmo.jpg)
how should i change the code to have keys untouched in the csv file?!

> NOTE:when i use `print(df)` i can see (as follow) that key is right and
> untouched so it may be a problem in `to.csv` part

```
  10024128313803797
0             42288
1             41851
2           2758249
3      115436583248
4           1194687
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not reproducible. I am able to see the csv fine.

Comment: may it be a problem with my microsoft excel?(i'm using office 2019)

Comment: Maybe. Please try opening the file in a text editor.

Comment: i used notepad and the numbers are fine!!
so what do you suggest for me to do?(i'm trying to do math operation in further .csv file)

Comment: Ok. You can post a new question stating new requirements with sample input data with expected output. I suggest not to edit this question to completely change it from original to something else.

Comment: thanks @MayankPorwal
i used excel>Data>From Text/CSV and imported the .csv to excel (without formatting) and all data are fine
so this question is closed.